# A specific site is returning a different response on python and in chrome

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to access a specific site using python,
and no matter which lib I use I just can't seem to access it.

I have tried Selenium+PhantomJS, I have tried requests and urllib.

Whenever I try to access the site from the browser I get a json file, and whenever I try to access it from a python script I get an html file (which has a huge minified script inside it)

I suspect this site is detecting I'm sending the request headlessly and is blocking my requests, but I can't figure out how.

The site address is:
http://www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON

I would very much appreciate if anyone can point me in the right direction.
Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's my selenium code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("http://www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON")
source = driver.page_source
```

At this point I print the source and see it is not what I expected.

Here is a requests implementation that also does not work:

```
import requests
res = requests.get("http://www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON")
source = res.content
```

The same happens here..

Comment: The web site returns Javascript that reloads the page from the real JSON site.

Comment: So why don't I get the json file anyway when I use selenium? Shouldn't it just redirect me? @Barmar

Comment: This site is protected by the rbzid session cookie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me if I set a bunch of headers including sending a cookie.

```
curl -H "Cookie:rbzid=d29SMXE1Rktrdm5kS2x0YW5EdVZwUzNpYVhWdUlJSndlVzEvUU9vWG5OU2dRSVNnWTc3TWYwaHN4V2REVGJyNFBMSFl1bXErMGFLNXNtUGxVb0ZwS3dVRDRhajEwczFMMmE3cUc1blBmaTEzeFZFWGhrbHgrUXhNeHRhZnhWNjBib1pTenM5bjFvOUhVRVoxOTNGRHBYQXQwVzVsYXdSSXliME5LeUZjU0Rhb2tHa09ycUNVYmJyOUVjMERJN3daaUlFUGhwUHpvT0dDblcwU0wwMEM3NlJZRGw1K1pXZ2NKNkJRTWhvNUtaZz1AQEAxOTVAQEAtNjY2NjY2NjYwNjA-" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ja;q=0.6" -H "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" http://www.yesplanet.co.il/presentationsJSON
```

[image]

Not sure which other headers are important

I looked at what headers chrome was sending by checking the network panel i the dev tools

[image]

From that I can also see chrome made 2 requests

Comment: When I run your code it still returns the html page.

Comment: maybe you need to get your own cookie

Comment: I have tried it with my own cookie, also when I checked the network panel I didn't see two requests, only one.. (same through fiddler)

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. There's a screenshot of my terminal showing it working. If I remove the cookie I get HTML, if I remove the other headers and not the cookie I get HTML. If I copy and paste that curl line I get json. I'm on a mac. Maybe your curl version is different?

Comment: Note, I only get 2 requests in the browser if I clear my cookies

Comment: Is there a programmatic way to get a cookie? other than manually going to chrome and copying it? If there is it might work for me as a patch (although I WOULD like to find the "proper" solution. Thanks for your comments btw!

Comment: The JavaScript sent in the first request is generating the cookie.

Comment: Can you please post a code segment that gets a cookie from the site  using Python?

Comment: You're saying that like you sent a js code segment that does the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136616/discussion-between-oryanm-and-gman).